# Consequences of fusing metallic glasses

Tags: metals, glass

I have come across some information about metallic glasses which has brought up questions. I have read that due to the need for high cooling rates generally, quantities of metallic glass are only produced in dimensions of width on the scale of a centimetre. I have also read that when metallic glasses are heated they begin to soften and flow like normal glasses which allows for them to be reshaped. This can be read on the [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amorphous_metal) under the section on history and the section on properties respectively.

Given these two pieces of information, why cannot metallic glasses be made of larger dimension by simply reheating multiple pieces to a temperature where they flow and fuse together? Will this fusion create weaknesses on the interface between the separate pieces? Am I misunderstanding the meaning of being deformed and being able to flow? Are there any experiments where anything like this has been attempted?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source of the information you provided?

Comment: Thanks for the link. But it's still hard to find that specific portion in the Wikipedia article. So please quote that portion. Or mention the heading.

Comment: A colleague worked on this when he was at Johns Hopkins. One wishes to avoid bulk heating, which would promote crystallization. See the discussion and references of Swiston et al., "Joining bulk metallic glass using reactive multilayer foils," *Scripta Materialia* 48 (2003). Check Google Scholar for the most recent work citing this paper.